# Alternative to die() if we have multiple PHP scripts (<?php ... ?>) in a single PHP file?

Tags: php, html

I am new to web development. I have the following `index.php` file:

```php
<H1>Form validation with my SQL integration </H1>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    emailid = <input type="text" name="tv_name" size="30" maxlength="32"><br>
    password = <input type="password" name="tv_pass" size="30" maxlength="11"><br>
    Press to create a new account: <input type="submit"  colspan="12" name="bt_register" value="Register!"><br>
    Press to get all: <input type="submit"  colspan="12" name="bt_getall" value="GetAll entries"><br>

</form>


<?php
    $req_type= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $data_arr =[];

    if($req_type=='GET' and isset($_GET["bt_register"]) ){
        $data_arr = $_GET;
    }
    elseif ($req_type=='POST' and isset($_POST["bt_register"]) ){
        $data_arr = $_POST;
    }

    else {
        die("wrong format response received<br>");
        // We didn't handle the first run flaw correctly.
        // Thus this message will be shown even if btregister is not pressed
    }

    echo strip_tags(""); # Converting key-string pair to key-array pair


    # Finding k-v pairs for each data
    foreach($data_arr as $i=> $value){
        echo "---- $i : $value <br>";
    }

    #... insertion/deletion/updation/creation

?>


<?php
    // I had to make a new one because old one would die at login press
    #---------------- reading our database ------------------------------------------

    $req_type= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; # Checking req type

    if($req_type=='GET' and isset($_GET["bt_getall"]) ){
        echo "Get all req received via get";
    }
    elseif ($req_type=='POST' and isset($_POST["bt_getall"]) ){
        echo "Get all req received via post";
    }

    else {
        die("no get all response received, dying now.");
    }
    echo "<br>";

?>
```

In the form, I have two buttons, `bt_register` and `bt_getall`. I also have two PHP scripts `<?php ...?>` for each of those button's tasks. The `bt_register` script had all the code to add an entry to MySQL console (removed for brevity). The `bt_getall` should have all the code to get entries from the SQL server.

When `bt_register` is pressed, the first script runs successfully followed by running the second script (which is a wrong, but understandable behaviour: I expected `bt_register` to run only the first script, but since the current php file has two scripts, it runs them both).

But when `bt_getall` is pressed, the first script's else case is hit and "wrong format response received" is displayed.

I am guessing that the usual working of PHP is this: on any submit button press, all the PHP scripts in a PHP file would be executed sequentially. If any PHP script calls `die("...")`, the complete execution would get halted.

So if I am correct in my guesses, what should be an alternative to `die` such that if current script is stopped, the other script could successfully run? I do want all my PHP scripts to remain in one file only, and the form buttons to run.

Or if there is an error in my approach, then let me know that too.

Comment: Throw an exception instead

Comment: Use 1 file for 1 script and include the one you need. Else use an Exception.

Comment: I feel `die()` is somewhat  similar to `return` keyword from java/other oop languages, if we assume that whole php file =  a java function. I want something like `break` or `continue` which would stop the current block's (i.e the current script in php file) execution , but not the whole function(i.e the complete php file )

Comment: It is not similar to return. `die()` stops the entire execution of PHP. The "return of PHP" is called `return` as well. Why not just use that? (with restructured code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind the conditions that you have imposed in your question,

> I do want all my PHP scripts to remain in one file only, and the form buttons to run

**I will suggest following solution to your problem**

```
<H1>Form validation with my SQL integration </H1>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    emailid = <input type="text" name="tv_name" size="30" maxlength="32"><br>
    password = <input type="password" name="tv_pass" size="30" maxlength="11"><br>
    Press to create a new account: <input type="submit"  colspan="12" name="bt_register" value="Register!"><br>
    Press to get all: <input type="submit"  colspan="12" name="bt_getall" value="GetAll entries"><br>
</form>


<?php
    $req_type= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $data_arr =[];

    if(isset($_REQUEST["bt_register"]) ){ // Executes for bt_register only
        $data_arr = $_REQUEST;

        if($req_type == "GET"){
            // Write operations that you want to perform for Register (when the method is GET)"

        }elseif($req_type == "POST"){
            // Write operations that you want to perform for Register (when the method is POST)"
        }else{
            throw new \Exception('Invalid method used');
        }
        // Write operations that you want to perform for all register requests (GET or POST)
        echo strip_tags(""); # Converting key-string pair to key-array pair

        # Finding k-v pairs for each data
        foreach($data_arr as $i=> $value){
            echo "---- $i : $value <br>";
        }
        #... insertion/deletion/updation/creation

    }elseif(isset($_REQUEST["bt_getall"])){ // Executes for bt_getall only
        if($req_type=='GET'){
            echo "Get all req recieved via get";
        }
        elseif ($req_type=='POST'){
            echo "Get all req recieved via post";
        }
        else {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid method used');
        }
        // Write operations that you want to perform for all getall requests (GET or POST)
    }elseif(isset($_REQUEST["bt_login"])){ // executes for bt_login only
        // Write code that should be executed on login button press
    }
    else { // executes for default page load or any other button press
        echo "<h2>First time load</h2>";
        // Write code (if any) that you want to run on first landing only.
    }

?>
```

#### Explanations of changes from your code

- `die()` should not be used as explained [in the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607014/alternative-to-die-if-we-have-multiple-php-scripts-php-in-a-single/60607400#60607400)
- With reference to your comment quoted below, it is useless to write `<?php ?>` tags again in this context. Writing new `<?php ?>` tags cannot invoke request that has already died

  > // had to make a new one because old one would die at login press
- `isset($_REQUEST["bt_register"]` gives you data irrespective of their method (GET or POST)
- Handle request type (register, get all, login, first load, etc.) using if-else, as explained in comments of the above-mentioned code

***I would recommend you to use different PHP files for every type of request instead of writing all of your code in a single index.php file.***

Answer (score 2):

`die()` should not be used in your web script. It is useful sometimes when debugging as a temporary measure, but using it in live application could lead to a disaster. A much better alternative is to use exceptions, which can be caught either by your application or by PHP itself.

```
if(/*this is not allowed*/) {
    throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to do this!');
}
```

In general you should design your application to have the least amount of unexpected situations like this. If it is not the fault of your application that something went wrong then your code should not be throwing any errors or exceptions. Write proper validations and structure the project in such a way, so that when a user provides invalid input they get a nice error message instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, literally, anything other than die().  ....including nothing at all.

For example:

```
$req_type= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; 
$data_arr =[];

if($req_type=='GET' and isset($_GET["bt_register"]) ){ 
    $data_arr = $_GET;
}
elseif ($req_type=='POST' and isset($_POST["bt_register"]) ){
    $data_arr = $_POST;
}
else{
//do whatever you want here, or nothing at all.
}
```

But, onto more helpful input.....

Why are your checking the request method?  You've set the form to POST.  Is some other form going to call this same script?  I think you want something more like this:

```
<?php 
$req_type= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; # checking req type

if($req_type=='POST' && isset($_POST["tv_name"]) && isset($_POST["tv_pass"]) ){  
    echo "Everything is as it should be";
}
else {
    //log the error
    error_log("Error with POST tv_name or tv-pass", 3, '/var/www/html/myfancyloggingfolder/didsomeonetrytoGET.log');
    //display an error message
    echo 'This message could be more robust, but either POST was not used or tv_name / tv_pass was not included.';
    // if you do not want the script to stop then do not use die or exit here.
}

?>
```

Comment: Updated with more helpful input.

Comment: Thank you . To answer your second question. i am new to web dev and learning about it. I am not sure if a server should always enforce a particular response type ( GET or POST) or should be flexible enough to handle both of them

Comment: If you were creating an API for the public to use and offer both methods, then you could have a script that handles both, but that's still not the way it is usually done.  In your case, the only thing accessing your server script is your own script.  So, no need to have it able to handle something that you're not going to throw at it.  That is, if you end up needing to GET for some other function, write a different PHP script to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

I am currently using the following approach of using functions to differentiate between different button calls. In this way, only the code that needs to be run on a button click would run because `isset (_REQTYPE[button_id])` is only set for a particular `button_id` every time a button is clicked , and is cleared afterwards. (Note that these are just my guesses because my code is working for me. Please feel free to add a better, more fact-supported reasoning):

```html
<?php
    $req_type= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; # Checking req type


    $data_arr =[];
    if($req_type=='GET' and isset($_GET["bt_reg"])) { # Pressing bt_reg would make a $_GET=[k1:v1, k2:v2,...] one of the pair will be "bt_reg":"Register!" . so checking if it's set
        $data_arr = $_GET;
        runRegisterCommands($data_arr);
    }
    elseif ($req_type=='POST' and isset($_POST["bt_reg"])) { # Pressing bt_reg would make a $_POST=[k1:v1, k2:v2,...] one of the pair will be "bt_reg":"Register!" . so checking if it's set

        $data_arr = $_POST;
        runRegisterCommands($data_arr);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------

    if($req_type=='GET' and isset($_GET["bt_getall"]) ){   # Same as above, but for bt_getall, since bt_getall won't be set up on bt_register click
        echo "Get all req received via get";
        runGetAllCommands();
    }
    elseif ($req_type=='POST' and isset($_POST["bt_getall"]) ){
        echo "Get all req received via post";
        runGetAllCommands();
    }
?>
```